# For loop implementation for rolling forecast origin with arima model in python

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

I implemented a for loop for rolling forecast origin with my test data on python using ARIMA modèles and it gave quite good results. I want now to predict future values while Still using rolling forecast origin but I have difficulties in doing that. Please someone help me get a for loop that Can Do this.

```
future_value=pd.date_range(start='2021-06-09',end='2021-06-30')
prediction_rolling=pd.Series()
for end in future_value:
    train=data2[:end-timedelta(days=1)]
    model=ARIMA(train,order=(1,1,3))
    model_aic=model.fit()
    pred=model_aic.predict(end)
    prediction_rolling.loc[end]=pred.loc[end]
```

Thi error shows:

```
KeyError: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'
```

And please for an example of a for loop code on python for predicting New values not found in dataset using rolling forecast origin

Comment: maybe you dont have a start value given here, then use slicing or iloc.

Comment: @Mehmaam I actually precised, it IS exactly the same code I used for the test data and it came out but when I want to predict future values it states this same error

Comment: Maybe I need to program the loop differently